# Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/u/ubuntu-advantage-tools/ubuntu-advantage-tools_27.8%7e22.04.1_amd64.deb

Tags: apt, server, 22.04

I installed a new Ubuntu 22.04 server. I can patch everything except `ubuntu-advantage-tools`

```
Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/u/ubuntu-advantage-tools/ubuntu-advantage-tools_27.8%7e22.04.1_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]
```

IPv4 and IPv6 are configured. I can ping, nslookup, and traceroute to [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) and ipv6.google.com on both IPv4 and IPv6.

I can ping both 91.189.91.38 and us.archive.ubuntu.com.

```
C:\Users\Win10x64i7>ping 91.189.91.38

Pinging 91.189.91.38 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 91.189.91.38: bytes=32 time=34ms TTL=50
Reply from 91.189.91.38: bytes=32 time=33ms TTL=50
Reply from 91.189.91.38: bytes=32 time=33ms TTL=50
Reply from 91.189.91.38: bytes=32 time=33ms TTL=50

Ping statistics for 91.189.91.38:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 33ms, Maximum = 34ms, Average = 33ms

C:\Users\Win10x64i7>ping us.archive.ubuntu.com

Pinging us.archive.ubuntu.com [2001:67c:1562::15] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 2001:67c:1562::15: time=29ms
Reply from 2001:67c:1562::15: time=29ms
Reply from 2001:67c:1562::15: time=29ms
Reply from 2001:67c:1562::15: time=28ms

Ping statistics for 2001:67c:1562::15:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 28ms, Maximum = 29ms, Average = 28ms
```

I checked the Fortinet 60E policy to make sure I had a policy for both the IP and FDQN.  Fortinet 60E does DNS for both IPv4 and IPv6.  I can reach the IP and FDQN on the Fortinet CLI.

Is the issue with `Ubuntu-Advantage-Tools`? I will open a call with Fortinet.

Here is the Fortinet output from diag.  We did
sudo apt update
sudo apt list --upgradable -a
sudo apt dist-upgrade

Firewall # 2022-05-06 08:37:36 id=20085 trace_id=1 func=print_pkt_detail line=5810 msg="vd-root:0 received a packet(proto=6, 172.16.1.2:41050->91.189.91.39:80) from internal2. flag [S], seq 4248892905, ack 0, win 64240"
2022-05-06 08:37:36 id=20085 trace_id=1 func=init_ip_session_common line=5981 msg="allocate a new session-00230483"
2022-05-06 08:37:36 id=20085 trace_id=1 func=vf_ip_route_input_common line=2589 msg="**Match policy routing id=2131427329: to 91.189.91.39 via ifindex-7"**
2022-05-06 08:37:36 id=20085 trace_id=1 func=vf_ip_route_input_common line=2615 msg="find a route: flag=04000000 gw-68.36.88.1 via wan2"
2022-05-06 08:37:36 id=20085 trace_id=1 func=fw_forward_handler line=803 msg="**Allowed by Policy-116: AV SNAT**"
2022-05-06 08:37:36 id=20085 trace_id=1 func=ids_receive line=298 msg="send to ips"
2022-05-06 08:37:36 id=20085 trace_id=1 func=av_receive line=314 msg="send to application layer"
2022-05-06 08:37:36 id=20085 trace_id=2 func=print_pkt_detail line=5810 msg="vd-root:0 received a packet(proto=6, 172.16.1.2:41050->91.189.91.39:80) from internal2. flag [.], seq 4248892906, ack 3880442433, win 502"

We setup an SD-WAN rule and tested on both WAN1 and WAN2.  Both get the same server error.

Here is the ping from the server

ping us.archive.ubuntu.com
PING us.archive.ubuntu.com(banjo.canonical.com (2001:67c:1562::15)) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from banjo.canonical.com (2001:67c:1562::15): icmp_seq=1 ttl=48 time=28.8 ms
64 bytes from banjo.canonical.com (2001:67c:1562::15): icmp_seq=2 ttl=48 time=28.8 ms
64 bytes from banjo.canonical.com (2001:67c:1562::15): icmp_seq=3 ttl=48 time=28.4 ms
64 bytes from banjo.canonical.com (2001:67c:1562::15): icmp_seq=4 ttl=48 time=30.1 ms
64 bytes from banjo.canonical.com (2001:67c:1562::15): icmp_seq=5 ttl=48 time=28.8 ms
64 bytes from banjo.canonical.com (2001:67c:1562::15): icmp_seq=6 ttl=48 time=28.2 ms
64 bytes from banjo.canonical.com (2001:67c:1562::15): icmp_seq=7 ttl=48 time=28.8 ms
64 bytes from banjo.canonical.com (2001:67c:1562::15): icmp_seq=8 ttl=48 time=28.8 ms
64 bytes from banjo.canonical.com (2001:67c:1562::15): icmp_seq=9 ttl=48 time=28.5 ms
64 bytes from banjo.canonical.com (2001:67c:1562::15): icmp_seq=10 ttl=48 time=28.9 ms
64 bytes from banjo.canonical.com (2001:67c:1562::15): icmp_seq=11 ttl=48 time=28.4 ms
64 bytes from banjo.canonical.com (2001:67c:1562::15): icmp_seq=12 ttl=48 time=28.3 ms
64 bytes from banjo.canonical.com (2001:67c:1562::15): icmp_seq=13 ttl=48 time=29.0 ms

ping -4 us.archive.ubuntu.com
PING  (91.189.91.39) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
---  ping statistics ---
31 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 30701ms

I called Fortinet back

Firewall # 2022-05-06 09:37:04 id=20085 trace_id=245 func=print_pkt_detail line=5810 msg="vd-root:0 received a packet(proto=1, 172.16.1.2:13->91.189.91.39:2048) from
internal2. type=8, code=0, id=13, seq=1."
2022-05-06 09:37:04 id=20085 trace_id=245 func=init_ip_session_common line=5981 msg="allocate a new session-0023422b"
2022-05-06 09:37:04 id=20085 trace_id=245 func=vf_ip_route_input_common line=2589 msg="Match policy routing id=2131623937: to 91.189.91.39 via ifindex-7"
2022-05-06 09:37:04 id=20085 trace_id=245 func=vf_ip_route_input_common line=2615 msg="find a route: flag=04000000 gw-68.36.88.1 via wan2"
2022-05-06 09:37:04 id=20085 trace_id=245 func=fw_forward_handler line=803 msg="Allowed by Policy-116: SNAT"
2022-05-06 09:37:04 id=20085 trace_id=245 func=ids_receive line=298 msg="send to ips"
2022-05-06 09:37:04 id=20085 trace_id=245 func=__ip_session_run_tuple line=3508 msg="SNAT 172.16.1.2->68.36.88.188:60429"
2022-05-06 09:37:04 id=20085 trace_id=245 func=ipd_post_route_handler line=490 msg="out wan2 vwl_zone_id 2, state2 0x10000, quality 1.
"

Firewall #

Server 91.189.91.39 is not responding to the ping -4 us.archive.ubuntu.com

I tried
sudo wget http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/u/ubuntu-advantage-tools/ubuntu-advantage-tools_27.8%7e22.04.1_amd64.deb
[sudo] password for michael:
--2022-05-06 16:34:11--  http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/u/ubuntu-advantage-tools/ubuntu-advantage-tools_27.8%7e22.04.1_amd64.deb
Resolving us.archive.ubuntu.com (us.archive.ubuntu.com)... 2001:67c:1562::18, 2001:67c:1562::15, 91.189.91.38, ...
Connecting to us.archive.ubuntu.com (us.archive.ubuntu.com)|2001:67c:1562::18|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden
2022-05-06 16:34:11 ERROR 403: Forbidden.

It is resolving the IPv6 address and still getting forbidden.

I found a workaround with the wget idea.  Thanks for you help.  user535733
I gave you an up mark.

I went to another server.  Used sudo wget http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/u/ubuntu-advantage-tools/ubuntu-advantage-tools_27.8%7e22.04.1_amd64.deb to download it.  Moved to with WINSCP to this server and did the install.  Fortinet and I went through the routing tables and policies.  Everything is working.  I checked the server Netplan setup.  Still no idea why only this file would error out on upgrading.  The rest of the 22.04 upgrades worked fine.

I removed dropbox22 and recreated it on a new interface.  Same forbidden error but on IPv6.

Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 ubuntu-advantage-tools amd64 27.8~22.04.1
403  Forbidden [IP: 2620:2d:4000:1::16 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/u/ubuntu-advantage-tools/ubuntu-advantage-tools_27.8%7e22.04.1_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden [IP: 2620:2d:4000:1::16 80]

ping -6 archive.ubuntu.com
PING archive.ubuntu.com(actiontoad.canonical.com (2620:2d:4000:1::16)) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from actiontoad.canonical.com (2620:2d:4000:1::16): icmp_seq=1 ttl=57 time=94.8 ms
64 bytes from actiontoad.canonical.com (2620:2d:4000:1::16): icmp_seq=2 ttl=57 time=93.2 ms
64 bytes from actiontoad.canonical.com (2620:2d:4000:1::16): icmp_seq=3 ttl=57 time=94.1 ms
64 bytes from actiontoad.canonical.com (2620:2d:4000:1::16): icmp_seq=4 ttl=57 time=93.3 ms
64 bytes from actiontoad.canonical.com (2620:2d:4000:1::16): icmp_seq=5 ttl=57 time=93.4 ms
64 bytes from actiontoad.canonical.com (2620:2d:4000:1::16): icmp_seq=6 ttl=57 time=93.6 ms
64 bytes from actiontoad.canonical.com (2620:2d:4000:1::16): icmp_seq=7 ttl=57 time=93.5 ms

ping -4 archive.ubuntu.com
PING  (91.189.91.39) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
---  ping statistics ---
12 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 11245ms

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?

Comment: Your ping command appears to be issued from a Windows machine ... Why is that?

Comment: I called Fortinet.  We tested the 
sudo apt update
sudo apt list --upgradable -a
sudo apt dist-upgrade

The fortinet 60E is allowing the traffic from the policy.  I don't have the characters to post the fortinet output from the diag.  

One thing I have noticed pinging that IP is it works some of the time.  It is like it is going up and down.

Comment: Unable to reproduce the problem: `wget http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/u/ubuntu-advantage-tools/ubuntu-advantage-tools_27.8%7e22.04.1_amd64.deb` downloads the package properly without error.